# How can I post request with order of json in swift with alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, alamofire

I need a payment method for my app and I have to post a request with JSON data for communicate with API. Everything seem correct to me. I can't find any bug in my code but I assume that JSON not post in order. Is this important? Because response said failure but I can't find anything else. If JSON order is important how can I make it? I'm new in swift please help me. 
Here my code:

```
 func mainRequestForPayment() {

      )

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "accept": "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorization": "\(self.authValue)",
            "x-iyzi-rnd": "\(self.randomString)",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        ]


        let url = "MY_URL"

        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "locale": "tr",
        "conversationId": "123456789",
        "price": "1.1",
        "paidPrice": "1.1",
        "installment": 1,
        "paymentChannel": "WEB",
        "basketId": "B67832",
        "paymentGroup": "PRODUCT",
        "paymentCard": [
            "cardHolderName": "CARD_HOLDER_NAME",
            "cardNumber": "CARD_NUMBER",
            "expireYear": "CARD_YEAR",
            "expireMonth": "01",
            "cvc": "123",
            "registerCard": 0
        ],
        "buyer": [
            "id": "BY789",
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "identityNumber": "74300864791",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "gsmNumber": "+905350000000",
            "registrationAddress": "Nidakule Göztepe, Merdivenköy Mah. Bora Sok. No:1",
            "city": "Istanbul",
            "country": "Turkey",
            "zipCode": "34732",
            "ip": "85.34.78.112"
        ],
        "shippingAddress": [
            "address": "Nidakule Göztepe, Merdivenköy Mah. Bora Sok. No:1",
            "zipCode": "34742",
            "contactName": "Jane Doe",
            "city": "Istanbul",
            "country": "Turkey"
        ],
        "billingAddress": [
            "address": "Nidakule Göztepe, Merdivenköy Mah. Bora Sok. No:1",
            "zipCode": "34742",
            "contactName": "Jane Doe",
            "city": "Istanbul",
            "country": "Turkey"
        ],
        "basketItems": [
            [
                "id": "BI101",
                "price": "0.3",
                "name": "Binocular",
                "category1": "Collectibles",
                "category2": "Accessories",
                "itemType": "PHYSICAL"
            ],
            [
                "id": "BI102",
                "price": "0.5",
                "name": "Game code",
                "category1": "Game",
                "category2": "Online Game Items",
                "itemType": "VIRTUAL"
            ],
            [
                "id": "BI103",
                "price": "0.2",
                "name": "Usb",
                "category1": "Electronics",
                "category2": "Usb / Cable",
                "itemType": "PHYSICAL"
            ]
        ],
        "currency": "TRY"
            ]


        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { (response) in
                print(parameters)
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    let swiftyJson = JSON(value)
                    print ("return as JSON using swiftyJson is: \(swiftyJson)")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print ("error: \(error)")
                }

        }


    }
```

Where is my fault I can't see? And again is there any way to make order in post request? Thanks all.

I get that response:

```
return as JSON using swiftyJson is: {
  "conversationId" : "123456789",
  "locale" : "tr",
  "errorCode" : "1000",
  "status" : "failure",
  "systemTime" : 1579858355103,
  "errorMessage" : "Invalid signature"
}
```

Comment: can you please post here your sample API Request parameter?

Comment: The *order* of the parameter dictionary is irrelevant as dictionaries are unordered anyway.

Comment: @HardikS These are my sample request parameters.

Comment: @vadian Okey if order not important for post request, can you see my mistake about that code?

Comment: The code itself seems to be correct, either the headers (are both string interpolated variables non-optional strings?) or the parameter keys and values could be wrong. What error do you get?

Comment: @makeser do you have a check that this API is working in postman? If it is working then please share the same screenshot of postman collection with API request param?

Comment: @vadian These two non optional type string. I add my response too.

Comment: @HardikS I will try with postman. Thanks.

Comment: If they’re optional you have to unwrap them otherwise you get an additional literal “optional” in your string. This could be the reason

Comment: @HardikS I also use postman now and its response samething. Is there any problem in server?

Comment: @vadian I'm sure these are non optional string. I already check them again. Is there problem in server?

Comment: There's a problem with the server communication. Please figure out what *Invalid signature* means.

Comment: @vadian I already search that invalid signature, I found that is according to json structure failures or auth key failure but I'm sure about these two are correct values.

Comment: @makeser please share the API request parameter like what parameter you need to send to API with what type of data your API param has required. So we can check it

Comment: @HardikS Here you can see documentation [link](https://dev.iyzipay.com/en/api/auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON order isn't typically important, as the JSON spec doesn't define it as a requirement for JSON objects, but some poorly engineered backends do require it. You really need to check the requirements of the backend you're communicating with.

Additionally, Swift's `Dictionary` type is arbitrarily ordered, and that order may change between runs of your app as well as between versions of Swift used to compile your code.

Finally, Swift's `JSONEncoder`, and Apple's `JSONSerialization` type both offer no way to require strict ordering. At most, `JSONSerialization` offers the `.sortedKeys` option, which will give you a guaranteed (alphabetical) order, but it may not be the order you declared your parameters in. Using an alternate `Encoder`, if you have `Codable` types (which I recommend instead of SwiftyJSON), may give you a better guarantee of order, but you should only really care if it's a requirement of your backend.

As an aside, I suggest you use the static `HTTPHeader` properties for your `HTTPHeaders` value, instead of using raw strings, it's much more convenient. For example:

```swift
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [.accept("application/json"),
                            .contentType("application/json")]
```

Comment: I need to ask question, my json body in question, is it correct?

Comment: That depends entirely on the requirements of the server you're communicating with.

Answer (score -2):

Use this class

//////////////////////////////////////////////

import Foundation

import UIKit

import Alamofire

class ServicesClass_New : NSObject
 {

```
var delegate : ServicesClassDelegate!

typealias CompletionBlock = (_ result : Dictionary<String, Any>?, _ error : Error?) -> Void
typealias CompletionDataBlock = (_ result : Data?) -> Void
typealias ProgressBlock = (_ progressData : Progress) -> Void

//MARK: Shared Instance

static let sharedInstance : ServicesClass = {
    let instance = ServicesClass()
    return instance
}()

static func getDataFromURlWith(url:String,parameters:Dictionary<String, Any>?, requestName:String,completionBlock : @escaping CompletionBlock)
{

    print("net available")
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value
            {
                //print(response.result.value!)
                //print(data)

                var dic : Dictionary<String,Any> = Dictionary()

                if data as? Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> != nil
                {
                    dic["data"] = data as? Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>
                    completionBlock(dic,nil)
                }
                else
                {
                    completionBlock(data as? Dictionary<String,Any>,nil)
                }
            }

            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error!)
            completionBlock(nil ,response.result.error!)
            break

        }
    }

}

static func postDataFromURL(url:String,parameters:Dictionary<String, Any>?, requestName:String,completionBlock : @escaping CompletionBlock)
{
    print("net available")
    //application/json 
    //multipart/form-data
    let hders : HTTPHeaders = [ "Content-Type" : "application/json"] as [String : String]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: hders).responseJSON { response in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let dict = response.result.value
            {
                let data = dict as! Dictionary<String,Any>

                // print(response.result.value!)
                // print(data)
                completionBlock(data as Dictionary,nil)
            }

            break

        case .failure(let error):
            print((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
            completionBlock(nil ,response.result.error!)
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

            break

        }
    }
}

static func downloadFile(strUrl : String, progressBlock : @escaping ProgressBlock, completionBlock : @escaping CompletionDataBlock)
{
    let utilityQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)

    Alamofire.request(URL.init(string: strUrl)!).downloadProgress(queue: utilityQueue, closure: { (progress) in

        progressBlock(progress)
    })
        .responseData { (response) in

            if let data = response.result.value
            {
                completionBlock(data)
            }
            else
            {
                completionBlock(nil)
            }
    }

}

static func uploadData(url:String,parameters:Dictionary<String, Any>,requestName:String,arrImg:[UIImage],arrVideos:[URL],completionBlock : @escaping CompletionBlock)
{

    print("net available")

    let hders = [

        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:
        {
            MultipartFormData in

            for img in arrImg
            {
                let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img , 0.8)!
                MultipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image" , fileName:"file\(index).jpg", mimeType:"image/jpeg")
            }

            index = 0
            for video in arrVideos
            {
                index = index + 1
                var videoData : Data = Data()
                do
                {
                    videoData = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: video.path))
                    MultipartFormData.append(videoData, withName: "video", fileName:"file\(index).mp4",mimeType: "video/mp4")
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            for (key, value) in parameters
            {
                MultipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }

    }, to:url,method:.post,headers:hders, encodingCompletion: {
        encodingResult in

        //["content-type" : "application/json"]
        switch encodingResult
        {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            print("image uploaded")
            upload.responseJSON { response in

                if let JSON = response.result.value
                {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }

                if let dict = response.result.value
                {
                    let data = dict as! Dictionary<String,Any>

                    print(response.result.value!)
                    print(data)

                    completionBlock(data as Dictionary,nil)

                }
            }

            break

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            completionBlock(nil ,encodingError)
            break
        }
    } )

}
```

}

/// call protocals where you want to call API.
//There is multiple Methods like : GET, POST 
....